# Google Spreadsheet REGEXREPLACE, get replacement from cell

Tags: regex, spreadsheet

I am working with google spreadsheet and we will use it creating product data.

Have a look at this screen:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/07f44br7bc

I will have the syntax of the product name in column A. In Column C, D and E I will have the content I need to replace in the syntax and then store the result in column B. Of course it should be generell working code, that it might work with more and less columns.

My idea is to use REGEXREPLACE code in column B and extract all contents between two ###. For example ###BRAND### will match BRAND. Now I will replace it with the content of coloumn name BRAND.

If it is possible to create a regex like this? Could anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

You could do some regexes like this to get your desired results, we are running the regexes on the `Syntax` field:

```
result = replace "^\#\#\#(.+)\#\#\# \#\#\#(.+)\#\#\# \#\#\#(.+)\#\#\#$" with "$1 $2 $3"
brand = replace "^\#\#\#(.+)\#\#\# \#\#\#(.+)\#\#\# \#\#\#(.+)\#\#\#$" with "$1"
type = replace "^\#\#\#(.+)\#\#\# \#\#\#(.+)\#\#\# \#\#\#(.+)\#\#\#$" with "$2"
oem = replace "^\#\#\#(.+)\#\#\# \#\#\#(.+)\#\#\# \#\#\#(.+)\#\#\#$" with "$3"
```

Here is a breakdown of the regex:

> ^ Matches the start of the string
>   \# Matches a literal # character
>   (.+) Matches string of characters, and is also a capturing group, which can be used in the replacements
>   $ Matches the end of the string

then, for the replacements

> $1 matches the first capturing group [the first (.+)]
>   $2 matches the second capturing group [the second (.+)]
>   $3 matches the third capturing group [the third (.+)]

Here's a regex 101 test: https://regex101.com/r/tD2kI3